# How to put path in variable without getting null exception

Tags: java, string, image

Im trying to do the quick following:

```
lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ItemDialog.class.getResource("/items/" + items.get(seed).getImage())));
```

however I am getting Null Pointer exception in the above line.

The program is running fine when I am using it in following manner.

```
lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ItemDialog.class.getResource("/items/item10312344.jpeg")));
```

it works.

EDIT: seed is the index number (1 in this case). items.get(1).getImage() holds the value of item10312344.jpeg but as above I get a null exception. but if manually input it, it works

what do I need to do to make this not get a null exception by getting it from the item list?

Comment: Can you put the code for items.get(seed).getImage().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to validate the object before calling "getImage"

```
//FIRST OF ALL: Make sure "items" is not null
if(items != null && items.get(seed) != null){
  ItemDialog itemDialog = ItemDialog.class.getResource("/items/" + items.get(seed).getImage())
  if(itemDialog != null)
  lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(itemDialog));
}

/*I am not sure about of which type is the object items is carrying, but a more
decent approach would be*/

if(items != null){
  "ObjectThatItemsIsCarrying" obj = items.get(seed);
  //Checking if you got the image name
  if(obj != null) 
  ItemDialog itemDialog = ItemDialog.class.getResource("/items/" + obj.getImage());
  //Cheking if you got the image
  if(itemDialog != null)
  lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(itemDialog));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the path in a string and use the string in the getResource method.

```
String path = "/items/" + item.get(seed).getImage();
```

Comment: Sorry, but how is this an answer? Are you confident it addresses OP's issue?

Comment: Don't know why but I had a somewhat similar problem which worked for the complete path but not if I was trying to stitch together parts of the path. This was what worked for me.